# NServiceBus Autofac child scope

Tags: c#, containers, inversion-of-control, autofac, nservicebus

I'm using NServiceBus 6 with NServiceBus.Autofac package.

I have some common interface ILogger which is registered in a custom Autofac Module (via overriding AttachToComponentRegistration method)

When I'm configuring NServiceBus with **child Autofac container**, unfortunately, all my message handlers could not resolve ILogger dependency.

```
        endpointConfiguration.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>(
        customizations: customizations =>
        {
            var childContainer = _container.BeginLifetimeScope();
            customizations.ExistingLifetimeScope(childContainer);
        });
```

However, everything works perfect when NServceBus is configured in the following way (without child scopes = only root container):

```
        endpointConfiguration.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>(
        customizations: customizations =>
        {
            customizations.ExistingLifetimeScope(_container);
        });
```

Does NServiceBus supports child Autofac scopes properly?

Comment: Added a [sample project](https://gitlab.com/alex_sk_/nsb_logging/blob/master/NSB_Logging/Program.cs#L35)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to how Autofac deals with modules in child lifetime scopes. It appears that modules within child scopes are not handled as expected. Github issue [here](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/218).

A quick fix is to re-register the module whenever you create a new lifetime scope:

```cs
endpointConfiguration.UseContainer<AutofacBuilder>(
customizations: customizations =>
{
    var childScope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope(b => b.RegisterModule<NLogModule>());

    customizations.ExistingLifetimeScope(childScope); // THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK PROPERLY
    //customizations.ExistingLifetimeScope(_container); // THIS LINE WORKS
});
```